# Abbreviating the xticks label values and describing each label value separtely on the sides of the bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have made a bar plot in which each bar is associated with a xticks label. But the issue as each label is a string of size 18. The plot looks ugly. So I abbreviated each string of the xticks label value to one character word. But I wanted to describe the each character separately on the sides of the plot. Is it possible to do this in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Maybe you just want a legend, won't you?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = '1234567890 abcdefghij ABCDEFGHIJ'.split()
heights = (7,3,4)
ticks = 'a b c'.split()

for t, h, l in zip(ticks, heights, labels):
    plt.bar(t, h, label=t+': '+l)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

---

Let's address OP's recent comment

[image]

```
...
plt.figure(layout='constrained', figsize=(8,3))
for t, h, l in zip(ticks, heights, labels):
    plt.bar(t, h, label=t+': '+l)
plt.legend(ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1), loc="upper left")
...
```